# How to create generic closures in Swift

Tags: swift, closures, block

I would like to create a function that uses generic closure (block) in swift.

My first attempt was to do like :

```
func saveWithCompletionObject(obj : AnyObject, success : AnyObject -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
```

But as soon as I call this function with another block, such as :

```
func doSomething(success : String -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject("Example", success, failure)
}
```

I get an error : `'AnyObject' is not a subtype of 'String'`

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have a look on this! It may help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778010/swift-selectors-and-closures-discussion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass a closure of type `String->Void` to a parameter of type `AnyObject->Void`.

However, you can define a *generic* function:

```
func saveWithCompletionObject<T>(obj : T, success : T -> Void, failure : Void -> Void) {
    // ...
    success(obj)
}
```

Now the compiler can verify that `obj` has the same type
as the parameter of `success`, for example:

```
func doSomething(success : String -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject("Example", success, failure)
}

func doSomethingElse(success : Int -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject(13, success, failure)
}
```

But I would recommend that `saveWithCompletionObject` just takes a `Void->Void`
parameter (without generics):

```
func saveWithCompletionObject(success : Void -> Void, failure : Void -> Void) {
    // ...
    success()
}
```

and the *caller* wraps its closure:

```
func doSomething(success : String -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject( { success("Example") } , failure)
}

func doSomethingElse(success : Int -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject( { success(13) }, failure)
}
```

This is more flexible, e.g. for callback functions with more than one
parameter:

```
func andNowForSomethingCompletelyDifferent(success : (Int, Double) -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
{
    saveWithCompletionObject( { success(13, M_PI) }, failure)
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of calling the function like `saveWithCompletionObject(String.class, success, failure)` so that the compiler knows what Type to use? How would the declaration of such function be like?