# What does the arrow ( -> ) between two types mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax

While researching a separate issue, I came across this SO question:
[How to create generic closures in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274141/how-to-create-generic-closures-in-swift#)

They have a function definition like this:

```
func saveWithCompletionObject(obj : AnyObject, success : AnyObject -> Void, failure : Void -> Void)
```

What does the `->` in `AnyObject -> Void` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s a [function type](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID174). `AnyObject -> Void` is the type of a function accepting `AnyObject` and returning `Void`.

Comment: Was it once a valid syntax? Now it requires parentheses around the argument.

Comment: @RoboRobok: Yeah, they’ve recently been reconciling the design conflict between multi-parameter functions and single-parameter functions that happen to take a tuple.

Answer (score 4):

```
success : AnyObject -> Void
```

This means that success parameter is a function that receives an object (AnyObject) and returns nothing (Void).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for closure expression separates Argument and Return type with a return arrow ->.